# How can I form a self join query in Apache-Solr from MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, solr

I need to do a self-join in Apache-Solr from MySQL.

An example:

```
select t2.city from table_name t1,table_name t2 where t1.city ='abc' and t1.company='def' and t1.name=t2.name and  t2.company='xyz';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Join Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) to do that, since you don't need any values from `t1`:

```
q={!join from=name to=name}city:abc AND company:def
fq=company:xyz
```

The resulting document should be the entry represented as `t2` in your example above.